# Как скачать файл с помощью Python?

Tags: python, файлы, url, requests, download

У меня есть [ссылка](https://lenta.com/contentassets/413fc8748e5c4b95a2a8f2b99a274ce5/LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf).
Хочу скачать этот файл(по ссылке) и узнать адрес, где лежит скачанный файл.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: есть пример кода в котором вы уже пытались это делать? если нет попыток то и нет большого желания помочь) советую посмотреть [документацию](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) по библиотеке `requests`

Comment: url = 'https://lenta.com/contentassets/413fc8748e5c4b95a2a8f2b99a274ce5/LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf", "LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf'
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "tutorial.pdf")
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
with open("tutorial1.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)

Comment: @Валера код в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии, с соответствующим форматированием. А чтобы обратиться к конкретному участнику, указывайте собаку + его ник - так он получит уведомление о сообщении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
destination = 'название файла'
url = 'ссылка'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, destination)
```

Он будет лежать в папке с проектом

Comment: AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Comment: @Валера Внёс изменения в код , посмотрите

Comment: raise InvalidURL(f"URL can't contain control characters. {url!r} "
http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/contentassets/413fc8748e5c4b95a2a8f2b99a274ce5/LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf", "LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf' (found at least ' ')

Answer (score 2):

`pip3 install wget`

```
import wget
wget.download('https://lenta.com/contentassets/413fc8748e5c4b95a2a8f2b99a274ce5/LN15_katalog_SM_SZFO_OMNI.pdf')
```

---

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)