# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/02/14/siteblank7f4f9eb1e7d2c454.png'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Код должен выполнить процедуру - взять фото с интернета и с помощью PIL ее отредактировать, в коде проблем нет, кроме как получения этой самой фотографии.

Не могли бы вы мне помочь, спасибо.

Мой код:

```
def montage_doc_site(text_1):

    image = Image.open('https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/02/14/siteblank7f4f9eb1e7d2c454.png')

    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 12)
    font_color = (255, 255, 255)

    position_1 = (580, 377)

    drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    drawing.text(position_1, text_1, font=font, fill=font_color)

    return image
```

Ошибка:

```
    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/02/14/siteblank7f4f9eb1e7d2c454.png'
```

Comment: Сперва скачайте файл, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal Не совсем понимаю для чего, обязательно скачать фото чтобы с ним работать?

Comment: Ну да, вроде бы никто нигде не обещал, что Pillow будет сам скачивать

Comment: @andreymal А не подскажете тогда как это сделать, если в дальнейшем программа должна работать на сервере? (Телеграм бот)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1156711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image.open` принимает или путь к локальному файлу, или файловый объект. А функция `urlopen` как раз возвращает файловый объект

Пример:

```
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen


image = Image.open(urlopen('https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/02/14/siteblank7f4f9eb1e7d2c454.png'))
print(image.size)
# (1364, 768)

image.show()
```

Модуль `io` содержит классы, которые реализуют API файловых объектов, поэтому если есть массив байт его можно обернуть в `BytesIO` и тот будет вести себя как файл, но в памяти.

Скачаем файл, получив массив байт, обернем в `BytesIO`:

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
from PIL import Image


rs = requests.get('https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/02/14/siteblank7f4f9eb1e7d2c454.png')
image = Image.open(BytesIO(rs.content))
print(image.size)
# (1364, 768)
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель) огромное спасибо. Лазил в интернете не особо нашел информации про это, от вас узнал что то новое

Comment: @Giga_Bird, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

Данная функция ищет файлы на локальном устройстве, вы указали внешнюю ссылку для протокола HTTP, автор данной библиотеки не мог и не должен был предусмотреть такой вариант.

Comment: Спасибо! Новая для меня информация)